# Variable duplicate as static and non-static

Tags: c#

So I have implemented an application that acts as a chatbot for telegram in C#. I use a library that allows to set a filter of updates that the application whishes to receive. I assume the filter makes it more performant. This filter is passed in the `StartReceiving` method. My bot consists of multiple modules and each of these may require different types of updates. So I have in each module a field `public IImmutableSet<UpdateType> UpdateTypeFilter`. When calling the `StartReceiving` function at the start of the application I union the sets of all modules to see what kind of updates I need to receive and then pass that.

```
//need to convert back to mutable set
ISet updateTypes = Module1.UpdateTypeFilter.ToHashSet();
//NOTE: UpdateTypeFilter is static
updateTypes.Union(Module2.UpdateTypeFilter);
telegramClient.StartReceiving(updateTypes);
```

This requires a static field since at this point the modules have not yet been created as the bot is not part of a chat yet. The modules are created when the bot is added to a chat:

```
void OnAddedToChat(Chat chat) {
  IList<Module> modules = new List() {
    new Module1(),
    new Module2()
  };
  //chats is of type Dictionary<long, IList<Module>>
  chats.Add(chat.Id, modules);
}
```

Then when actually receiving updates I filter for each module according to which update type they wish to receive.

```
void OnMessageReceived(Message message) {
  IList<Module> modules = chats.GetValueOrDefault(message.Chat.Id);
  if(modules == null) {
    //The bot has just been added to the chat.
    OnAddedToChat(message.Chat);
    return;
  }
  foreach(Module module in modules) {
    //Note UpdateTypeFilter cannot be static
    if(module.UpdateTypeFilter.Contains(message.Type)
      module.ProcessMessage(message);
  }
}
```

As already commented in the code once the `UpdateTypeFilter` has to be static and once not. How can I solve this nicely? So far I just have two variables where one is called 'UpdateTypeFilterStatic' but that is not nice. I could move the filtering to the modules themselves. Then I can use the static variable both times but then it would be duplicate code in each module since I cannot generalize it into the interface. And duplicate code is not nice either.

Any ideas how to make it nicer are welcome :)

Comment: There is so much missing that I doubt anyone will be able to give you any good advice. It'd be best if you posted the complete class(es) so that we can see the big-picture too.